# httplistener with post data

Tags: c#, json, httplistener

I'm looking at creating a small windows service that will communicate with clients via JSON. I've created a simple HttpListener sample and that's working correctly.

My question is how do i go about retrieving the JSON data from a client(POST)?

thanks

Answer (score 34):

When you accept a request from `HttpListener`, you get an [`HttpListenerContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenercontext.aspx). From there, you can get an [`HttpListenerRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerrequest.aspx) - and that has an [`InputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerrequest.inputstream.aspx) property which you can read the data from.

To read text data (such as JSON) you can use the [`ContentEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerrequest.contentencoding.aspx) property and build a `StreamReader`. For example:

```
var context = listener.GetContext();
var request = context.Request;
string text;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream,
                                     request.ContentEncoding))
{
    text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
// Use text here
```

Comment: That's interesting but request.InputStream can be System.IO.Stream.Null sometimes, even when I am explicitly sending data. Also, how do I read distinct files ? Are they fused into a single InputStream?

Comment: @IvanP.: In which case I'd expect that to make `text` and empty string, because the request doesn't contain any data in the body. If the stream is `Stream.Null`, I suspect you've not *actually* sent data correctly. I see you've now added more information in the comment, including two further questions - those should really be in new posts, as they aren't related to this original question.

Comment: Thank you for response, but I am trying to expand your answer to work with binary data sent through `post`

Comment: @IvanP.: Sounds like you need to ask a new question.